# Cannot connect RXStompJS between Angular and Spring

Tags: angular, spring, websocket

I have troubles when trying to connect Angular client with RxStompJS and Spring backend.
The issue is that on the backend side connection seems to be established, but on the client side it's not.

This is websocket spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/player");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new HandshakeHandler());
    }
}
```

And that's my WebSocketService in Angular

```
export class WebSocketService {

  private client: RxStomp | undefined;

  constructor() {
    this.connect();
  }

  private connect(){

    this.client = new RxStomp();
    this.client.configure({
                brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws',
                connectHeaders: {
                  login: 'guest',
                  passcode: 'guest'
                },
                heartbeatIncoming: 0,
                heartbeatOutgoing: 20000,
                reconnectDelay: 200,
                debug: (msg: string): void => {
                  console.log(new Date(), msg);
                  console.log(this.client?.connected());
                }
              });

    this.client.activate();
  }
```

[Spring log when establishing connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpFYL.png)
[Web browser logs from client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfTGR.png)

When using regular Stomp.Client, even though 'active' field is true and 'connected' field is undefined, publishing and subscription works, however subscription must be established manually, because client.onConnect() is not even firing up.

I'm using Angular 17, Spring 3.2.2, StompJS 7.0.0 and RxStompJS 2.0